# Converting to async,await using async targeting package

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, async-await

I have this:

```
private void BtnCheckClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        var a = txtLot.Text;
        var b = cmbMcu.SelectedItem.ToString();
        var c = cmbLocn.SelectedItem.ToString();
        btnCheck.BackColor = Color.Red;
        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
                           Dal.GetLotAvailabilityF41021(a, b, c));
        task.ContinueWith(t =>
        {
                btnCheck.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
                lblDescriptionValue.Text = t.Result.Description;
                lblItemCodeValue.Text = t.Result.Code;
                lblQuantityValue.Text = t.Result.AvailableQuantity.ToString();
        },TaskScheduler .FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() );
        LotFocus(true);
}
```

and i followed J. Skeet's advice to move into async,await in my .NET 4.0 app. I converted into this:

```
private async void BtnCheckClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        var a = txtLot.Text;
        var b = cmbMcu.SelectedItem.ToString();
        var c = cmbLocn.SelectedItem.ToString();
        btnCheck.BackColor = Color.Red;
        JDEItemLotAvailability itm = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Dal.GetLotAvailabilityF41021(a, b, c));
        btnCheck.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        lblDescriptionValue.Text = itm.Description;
        lblItemCodeValue.Text = itm.Code;
        lblQuantityValue.Text = itm.AvailableQuantity.ToString();
        LotFocus(true);
}
```

It works fine. What confuses me is that i could do it without using Task but just the method of my Dal. But that means that i must have modified my Dal method, which is something i dont want?

I would appreciate if someone would explain to me in "plain" words if what i did is optimal or not and why.

Thanks

P.s. My dal method

```
public bool CheckLotExistF41021(string _lot, string _mcu, string _locn)
{
        using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(this.conString))
        {
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "select lilotn from proddta.f41021 " +
                                        "where lilotn = ? and trim(limcu) = ? and lilocn= ?";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lotn", _lot);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mcu", _mcu);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@locn", _locn);
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                OleDbDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                bool _retval = rdr.HasRows;
                rdr.Close();
                con.Close();
                return _retval;
        }
}
```

Comment: Could you show some dal code plesae? why and how do you want to change it?

Comment: Its a simple OledbDataReader with an OleDbconnection. with change i ment that if ididnt use Task, i would have to decoratemy dal method with async and await on the fetching statement?

Comment: @ArsenMkrt: i added the dal method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's not optimal at all. If you cannot change your DAL layer to be asynchronous you are not gaining much by using async/await. You are simply running your blocking DAL method inside a seprate background thread. If you want real gain, you should modify your DAL method to use asynchronous ADO.NET, a.k.a BeginXXX and EndXXX methods. Once you do that you will get real benefit from I/O Completion Ports. No threads will ever be jeopardized during the execution of the database call.

If you cannot modify your DAL method, whether you are using `JDEItemLotAvailability itm = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Dal.GetLotAvailabilityF41021(a, b, c));` or manual thread creation, really, you gain nothing.

Comment: I see. My main concern in this particular app (which is very simple) is not to have my main form lock while it performs the dal operations. these dal operations are very simple and fast. Thanks.

Comment: Well, then running them in separate threads should be enough for you. You will no longer be blocking the main thread. But since you've asked about the optimal solution, in your case, that would be to modify your DAL method to use asynchronous ADO.NET.

Comment: It's "not optimal" in the sense that it will tie up a thread pool thread while the db operation is going. But it's perfectly "optimal" in the sense that it achieves the primary goal of `async` operations in GUI apps: improved responsiveness.

Comment: @StephenCleary, sure, I was just saying that you gain nothing by using async/await in this case. You could have used a standard background thread. What I tried to make clear in my answer is that async/await is not some magic stick. Those 2 keywords won't bring any benefit automatically to any existing code. They are simplifying the syntax and are only syntactic sugar to already good written asynchronous code. Lots of people are fooled into thinking that, well, I shall stick those async/await keywords in my code, and I'm gonna improve my legacy synchronous I/O calls. No, that's a myth.

Comment: But by using the async ,CLR automatically creates a new thread for the task i want to complete. Isntt that a quick way to create the background thread?

Comment: @e4rthdog, no, not at all. You could have used a simple background thread for this case. `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` or an asynchronous delegate, or even TPL (`Task.StartNew`) which is the recommended pattern now.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, by TPL you mean what i have done in my first code snippet, yes?

Comment: @e4rthdog, in your first 2 snippets you are using TPL - `Task.Factory.StartNew`. They are perfectly equivalent. The first one is .NET 4.0 and the second one is using the async/await keywords introduced in .NET 4.5. In terms of performance they are absolutely the same. The synchronous I/O operation is executed on a background thread without blocking the main thread. But still blocking the background thread.

Comment: No, it's not an overkill. It's just syntactic sugar to write the same thing. Look at your first snippet. You are using the `ContinueWith` method on the task and writing the continuation inside the anonymous method. In the second snippet you no longer need that because, `async/await` is syntactic sugar that the C# 5.0 compiler understands and converts for you behind the scenes to a `ContinueWith` call. Your code still looks synchronous and more readable.

Comment: And in order to correctly use the async/await pair, i should not use TPL and create the "await" methods in such way that i will gain performance..Correct? somehow?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by *correctly*. Currently you are correctly using them. There's nothing wrong with your code. But that's not the optimal solution. If you want the optimal solution, that has strictly nothing to do with any TPL or any async/await. You have to modify your DAL method to use the BeginXXX and EndXXX ADO.NET methods. That's the first step. Then it's easy to wrap in TPL and async/await. But without having real asynchronous DB calls you gain nothing.

Comment: Note that ADO.NET has XXXAsync versions of the data access methods in .NET 4.5. E.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh223678.aspx